# Пунктуация, вводные слова

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый день! Прошу Вас разъяснить пунктуацию в следующем предложении:
"В течение месяца в наличии будет свекла и капуста, может раньше". Весь наш офис считает, что после "может" запятой нет. Мне кажется, что это вводное слово, выражающее степень уверенности говорящего, и поэтому оно должно выделяться запятыми с обеих сторон. Рассудите нас, пожалуйста! :) Правила русского языка о вводных словах распечатывала, но они их не убедили.

Comment: Это степень неуверенности типа "возможны осадки". Для любой переписки, тем более, как можно понять, деловой переписки совершенно не годится также и укороченное "может" из "может быть".

Comment: Сначала нужно задуматься о содержании этого предложения. В течение месяца капуста будет, а раньше - это когда?

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд прежде всего предложение не совсем корректно построено. В течение месяца - это ведь в этом месяце, а следовательно непонятно как истолковывать слово *раньше*. Допустим была бы понятнее следующая форма:

"В конце месяца в наличии будет свекла и капуста, может раньше"

> Одни и те же слова могут употребляться то в качестве вводных (стало
>   быть, не членов предложения), то в качестве **членов предложения** (чаще
>   всего сказуемых или **обстоятельств**).
>
> *Вы, **верно**, переведены сюда из России? (Лермонтов). – Вы **верно** перевели
>   этот отрывок?*
>
> *Цех, **возможно**, уже реорганизован. – Цех **возможно** реорганизовать.*
>
> Синтаксическая роль подобных слов обусловлена контекстом, и проверить
>   ее можно путем изъятия этих слов из состава предложения: в одном
>   случае (без вводного слова) структура предложения сохраняется (*Цех уже
>   реорганизован*), в другом (без члена предложения) – чаще всего
>   распадается (*Цех… реорганизовать*, без интонации побуждения).

[Д.Э.Розенталь. Справочник по правописанию и стилистике](http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxvi.html)

В нашем случае без слова **может** структура предложения распадается, а следовательно, вполне вероятно, что слово **может** в данном предложении является обстоятельством.

> Обстоятельство в синтаксисе русского языка  второстепенный член
>   предложения, зависящий от сказуемого и обозначающий признак действия
>   или признак другого признака.

По поводу вот этого замечания: "Следует, однако, иметь в виду, что если с изъятием слова или словосочетания структура предложения распадается, то это еще не служит доказательством того, что изъятые слова — члены предложения..."

> Место вводных слов, вводных предложений и
>   сочетаний в предложении свободное; они легко 
>   за­нимают позиции в начале, в конце или в середине
>   предложения, **свободно вводятся в него и свободно
>   из него изымаются**. Синтаксические связи с ка­ким-­либо
>   членом предложения или с предложением
>   в целом у вводных слов, вводных сочетаний и ввод­ных
>   предложений отсутствуют: даже если в составе
>   вводимой группы есть союз, он в этих случаях не
>   выполняет связующей функции: *Он болен и, что
>   еще хуже, совершенно одинок; Сюда, как говорят,
>   едет делегация; Приедет, если не ошибаюсь, 
>   человек сто.*
>   Все эти признаки объединяют вводные слова,
>   вводные сочетания слов и вводные предложения в
>   особую лексико­синтаксическую группировку.

Русская грамматика. Т. 2: Синтаксис / Н. Ю. Шведова (гл. ред.).
§2220

Comment: Петр, цитирую Розенталя.  Однако в некоторых случаях предложения двузначны, и указанный прием проверки не дает нужных результатов: структура предложения сохраняется как при изъятии вводного слова, так и при изъятии члена предложения. Ср.:

Прежде всего нужно говорить именно об этом («сначала»). – Прежде всего, нужно ли говорить именно об этом? (указывается связь мыслей).

Он безусловно прав (обстоятельственное слово; указывается степень его правоты). – Он, безусловно, прав (вводное слово; указывается на уверенность в его правоте).

Comment: Ну да, но в нашем случае ведь не сохраняется.

Comment: Следует, однако, иметь в виду, что если с изъятием слова или словосочетания структура предложения распадается, то это еще не служит доказательством того, что изъятые слова — члены предложения: А вы подумайте, может, и другой вариант приемлем; Кто знает, может быть, показатели были бы более высокие; Если выписать цифры столбиком, возможно, и расчёты упростятся — в этих случаях вводные слова играют роль структурного элемента предложения.

Comment: Просто некорректно построено предложение. Здесь имеется ввиду вероятность действия.т.е. выражается степень уверенности. Иначе получится, что здесь свекле и капусте приписывается какая-то способность.

Comment: Но Алла утверждает: "что это вводное слово, выражающее степень уверенности говорящего". Степень уверенности в чём?

Comment: Способность появиться где-то раньше срока

Comment: В том, что автор полагает, что свекла, капуста возможно появятся раньше срока.

Comment: Ну где же здесь уверенность, если автор считает, что свекла и капуста может появится, а может и нет?

Comment: Степень уверенности.

Comment: Ну какая же может быть степень уверенности, если в данном случае человек выражает скорее неуверенность в том, когда появиться свекла и капуста? То есть он не знает точно (не уверен) когда случится данное событие.

Comment: Простите, я некорректно выразился. Я имел в виду оценку говорящим степени достоверности сообщаемого.

Comment: Ну другими словами человек достоверно знает лишь то, что событие случится, а словом _может_ он выражает своё незнание того, когда случится это событие. То есть событие появления свеклы и капусты в определённом месте и так абсолютно очевидно и пишушему предложение, и читающему его, то есть само это предложение уже подтверждает то, что свекла и капуста будут в наличии, а вот когда это произойдёт - человек не уверен и использует для передачи неуверенности слово _может_.

Comment: Нет, степень достоверности понятие широкое - от уверенности до неуверенности.

Comment: Но почему же тогда вы в этом пояснении не выделили запятыми слово _возможно_?
"В том, что автор полагает, что свекла, капуста возможно появятся раньше срока."

Comment: Опечатка. Увы, исправить не могу!

Comment: @Пётр<<...неуверенность в том, когда появитЬся свекла и капуста?>> - как-то неловко на сайте Русский язык наблюдать этот чертов мягкий знак там, где ему никак не место!

Comment: Ну да, просто очень эмоционально набирал сообщение ))

Answer (score 1):

В примере, которой Вы приводите, "может" - действительно вводное слово. Но оно стоит в конце обособленного оборота и не выделяется запятой.

Подробнее об этом здесь: [Розенталь. Д. Э. Справочник по пунктуации.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122)

Comment: В конце оборота?

Comment: Екатерина, в чем Вы сомневаетесь?

Comment: В начале обособленного оборота.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что вводное слово находится в начале обособленного оборота? Я вас правильно понял?

Answer (score 0):

В течение месяца в наличии будет свекла и капуста, может раньше.

Строго говоря, семантика предложения некорректна, но смысл понятен: раньше - это, к примеру, в течение недели.

Что касается грамматики, то слово  "может" выполняет функцию присоединительного союза для уточняющего обстоятельства (сужение значения: в течение месяца - раньше) и не обособляется.

Розенталь: Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется: "Спокойно потягивает трубочку смуглый, коренастый капитан, по-видимому (=может быть) итальянец или грек".

Другой вариант:

"В течение месяца в наличии будет свекла и капуста, а может, раньше".

В этом случае вводное СОЧЕТАНИЕ "а может" выполняет свою вводную функцию.

Comment: Вера, а где в правилах написано, что вводные слова могут выполнять функцию присоединительного союза?

Comment: У Лопатина § 84: В выходные можно отдохнуть, например поехать за город.

Comment: Вера, там говорится о добавочном сообщении. И о таких словах, как в частности, таким образом, и т.д. Слово "может" не входит в этот список.

Comment: Серж, какой список? Видимо, должно быть, вероятно и др. - все эти вводные слова могут быть присоединительными союзами.  "Может и может быть" ничем от них не отличаются.

Comment: Вера, но здесь нет добавочных сообщений.

Comment: Такие конструкции обычно присоединяются словами даже, особенно, в особенности, например, главным образом, в частности, в том числе, притом, и притом, причём, и (‘и притом’), да, да и, да и вообще, да и только и др.:

Comment: В течение месяца в наличии будет свекла и капуста, даже , может быть,  раньше. Важно, что отношения между обстоятельствами неоднородные, это уточнение или уточнение в добавочном сообщении (совершенно без разницы). Признак назван, а потом он уточняется.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, вводное слово.

*...может, [будет] раньше* — так уж совсем понятно.

А то, что предложение составлено крайне неудачно — и стилистически, и семантически — это да.

Comment: Уважаемый Niemand! Знаки препинания выбираются для конкретного предложения, в которое не надо ничего добавлять, чтобы было "совсем понятно", иначе это будет уже другое предложение с другими знаками препинания.

Comment: Vera, тут нет добавления. В квадратных скобках - опущенное слово, восстановленное для лучшего понимания смысла и оснований для запятой.

Comment: Vera, сравните: Он приедет через неделю, а может, [приедет] раньше. Он приедет через неделю, а может [приехать] раньше. Так вот, в исходном предложении второй вариант невозможен, а значит, это вводное слово, запятая необходима.

Answer (score 0):

Предложение построено неправильно. Нагляднее так:

*Свекла и капуста будут в наличии в течение месяца, может, раньше.* Но поскольку в данном случае возникает двусмысленность ("в течение месяца, может" или "может, раньше"), то:

1) запятая превращается в тире: *Свекла и капуста будут в наличии в течение месяца - может, раньше.*

2) или вторая запятая убирается, тем самым вводное слово само создает обособленный оборот: *Свекла и капуста будут в наличии в течение месяца, может раньше.*

Корявый исходник сути дела не меняет:

*В течение месяца в наличии будет свекла и капуста - может, раньше.*
*В течение месяца в наличии будет свекла и капуста, может раньше.*

Не согласна, что это однозначно уточнение. Тут просится простой разделительный ИЛИ. Лично мне больше нравится вариант с тире.

Comment: А когда это раньше? Напрашивается - вчера и ранее!   Зачем же обсуждать явную белиберду?